# Gravitons in a vacuum

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, vacuum, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

I'm new so please be nice if I don't know too much about anything.
I was kind of curious about the idea of gravitons in a vacuum. (using string theory, or even superstring theory.) if space is a near-perfect vacuum, how does it have enough gravitons (if any), to keep planets spinning in the orbit of a star? (again please be nice I'm 14 and know virtually nothing if I have like 8 fundamentals wrong, could you please explain where I went wrong.)

Comment: But graviton is the hypothesized elementary particle consisting the fabric of spacetime or else the theorized (unproven) elementary particle that consists the vacuum. Does this resolve your confusion?

Comment: There are no more gravitons in vacuum than there are photons or electrons. Imagining quanta as physical objects is one of worst mental models in physics. I would suggest that you get rid of it as soon as you can. A quantum is an irreversible energy exchange between a quantum field and an external physical system. That exchange simply goes hand in hand with an angular momentum exchange of one (or in case of gravity two) Planck units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resorting to gravitons here is not helpful. When LIGO detected gravitational waves (GW) by moving a 40 kg mirror less then 1/1000-th the diameter of a proton, there were on the order of $10^{30}$ gravitons incident on the mirror.

The mirror was moved by a brief passage of a GW, which is more simply seen as ripples in the space-time metric, just as light is ripples in the electromagnetic field.

Meanwhile, a planet is held in its orbit by a much less ethereal curvature, for which a graviton description is possible, but not helpful.

Since you're starting-out, you will see a lot of material saying forces are due to exchanged particles...this generally just leads to confusion for beginners, as it gets taken too literally, and the fact that the particles can have negative energy or zero energy with finite momentum gets overlooked when trying to imagine  a reaction force via intuition.

Anyway, the vacuum is usually considered "spacetime". Well, GWs are just spacetime, so distinguishing a vacuum in space with or without GWs is somewhat meaningless. Rather, they're both vacuum solutions to Einstein's Field Equations. One static, one dynamic.

Finally: I will say here with extreme certainty: A single graviton will never be observed in the lab. All it is is the minimum quantized difference of spacetime from flat spacetime, so it's not really what you think of as a particle. (Similar arguments can be made about the photon...e.g., it's not a point).

It's somewhat a language issue, where we call minimum quantized excitations of quantum fields just: "particles", and double that confusion for "virtual particles".

Comment: Does this mean that this vacuum is space-time and that gravity / GWs are the distortions of this vacuum but not something passing through the vacuum? But more rather a measure of the distortions in space-time?

Answer (score 0):

The statement "space is a vacuum" does not mean "there are no particles travelling through space." It simply means that there are relatively much fewer *atoms* in space than in Earth's atmosphere. Light and the influence of gravity freely travel through space without changing the
fact that it's a vacuum.

Also note that your conceptual issue would also apply to light - light also travels through the vacuum (in the form of photons). That's why you can see the sun. So we don't need to go all the way to gravitons from string theory to see that particles fly through space. This also happens in well-established physics.

Finally string theory and superstring theory are different names for the same thing.

Comment: But it would still be better to tell the OP not to think of photons as "flying through space". That is a failed mental model that causes more trouble than it is worth. It explains almost nothing and what it explains it explains in the wrong way.

Comment: @FlatterMann I actually have no idea what you're talking about. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A quantum is an amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges. It is being exchanged between systems in an irreversible process. This is what we teach when we teach the photoelectric effect, even at the high school level. Curiously people (including Einstein in his 1905 PE paper!) immediately jump to the conclusion that this energy has to have location and move along a path in vacuum, like a little classical ball. Neither experiments not theory support this mental model of quanta. IMHO this is more of a psychological "objectification" effect. It is not proper scientific thinking.